# Unable to add Scroll pane in the following code..?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class Note implements ActionListener
{
   JFrame jf;
   JMenuBar menubar;
   JMenu file,edit,search,about_me;
   JMenuItem menuitem;
   JFileChooser jfc;
   JTextArea area=new JTextArea();
   JScrollPane jp;

   Note(String k)
   {
      jfc=new JFileChooser("e:\\java");

      jf=new JFrame(k);
      menubar=new JMenuBar(); 

      file=new JMenu("File");
      file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

      menuitem=new JMenuItem("New");
      menuitem.setActionCommand("New");
      menuitem.addActionListener(this);
      menuitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      file.add(menuitem);

      menuitem=new JMenuItem("Open");
      menuitem.setActionCommand("open");
      menuitem.addActionListener(this);
      menuitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      file.add(menuitem);

      menuitem=new JMenuItem("Save");
      menuitem.setActionCommand("save");
      menuitem.addActionListener(this);
      menuitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
      file.add(menuitem);

      menuitem=new JMenuItem("Save as...");
      menuitem.setActionCommand("save_as");
      menuitem.addActionListener(this);
      file.add(menuitem);

      file.addSeparator();
      menuitem=new JMenuItem("Exit");
      menuitem.setActionCommand("exit");
      menuitem.addActionListener(this);
      file.add(menuitem);

      jf.add(area);
      jf.setVisible(true);
      jf.setSize(400,400);
      menubar.add(file);
      //menubar.add(edit);
      jf.setJMenuBar(menubar);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("New"))
         area.setText("NEw");
      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("open"))
      {
         String m=open(jfc);
         System.out.println(m);
         try{
            FileInputStream p=new FileInputStream(m);
            int i=0;char k;String k1="";
            while((i=p.read())!=-1)
            {
               k=(char)i;
               k1=k1.valueOf(k);
               area.append(k1);}
               //System.out.println(k1);
               p.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e1){
               System.out.println(e1);
            }
      }

      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("save"))
      {
          String m=save(jfc);
          try{
             FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(m,true);
             String s=area.getText();
             char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
             for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
             fw.write(ch[i]);
             fw.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e1)
          {
              System.out.println("Exception occurs"+e1);
          }
      }
      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("save_as"))
         area.setText("save_as");

      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("exit"))
         System.exit(0);
   }

   public static String open(JFileChooser jfc) 
   {
      int x=jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
      if(x==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
      {
         File f=jfc.getSelectedFile();
         String w=f.getPath();
         char ch[]=w.toCharArray();
         for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
         {
            if(ch[i]==92)
               ch[i]=47;
         }
         String w1=new String (ch);
         return w1; 
      }
      else return null;
   }

   public static String save(JFileChooser jfc) 
   {
      int x=jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
         if(x==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
         {
            File f=jfc.getSelectedFile();
            String w=f.getPath();
            char ch[]=w.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
            {
               if(ch[i]==92)
               ch[i]=47;
            }
         String w1=new String (ch);
         return w1; 
      }
      else return null;
   }

   public static void main(String... s)
   {
      new Note("Ankit");
   }
}
```

Actually, when the first time i use Scrollpane its on the JTable. So it added perfectly but this time it is not. I make a refrence variable for Jscrollpane and when i create an instance of this then i give.... 
//jsp=new JScrollPane(area);
but nothing happens. It seems that it is somewhere related with Layouts. So can anyone helps me to figure this out.

Comment: You don't seem to be adding jp do anything. You add area, which removes it from the jp and adds it to the frame. Think of it like this. The JTextArea is the casserole, the JFrame is the fride, you need to put the casserole into some kind of container before you add it to the fridge, this is what the JScrollPane is, it's the tuppaware container into which you place the casserole and it's the tuppaware container you add to the fridge

Comment: Sorry,didn't get you!!

Comment: i have tried jp=new JScrollPane(area); & u ask for jp=new JScrollPane(jf);??

Comment: Did you add `jp` to the frame?

Comment: yes but nothing happens